# MongoDB opposite of $addToSet

Tags: mongodb, database

I'm aware of the [$addToSet](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/addToSet/) method for MongoDB, but I can't find a "remove" equivalent anywhere in the docs.

What's the best way to achieve this? Trying to achieve something like the following:

```
obj = {
  name: 'object1',
  tags: ['fus', 'ro', 'dah']
}

db.collection.update({
  name: 'object1'
}, {
  $removeFromSet: {
    tags: 'dah'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 116, accepted):

I think you are looking for [$pull](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/pull/), which "removes all instances of a value from an existing array".

```
db.collection.update(
  {name: 'object1'}, 
  {$pull: { tags: 'dah'}});
```

Comment: Great. Wish there was reference to this somewhere in the docs.

Comment: All the array operators can be found here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update-array/#update-operators

Comment: How to remove multiple elements from an array with a single command?

Comment: @SurenderThakran You also use $pull like above, for ex: `{ $pull: { tags: { $in: ["dah", "dex"] } } }`